# How to get text between data and comma in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indexing

I am parsing text from a website, where I got a string:

```
"Some Event 21.08.2019—31.08.2019 Standart (1+1) ,  Some text"
```

or something similar. I need to get text beetween last **date** and **comma**.
Here is `"Standart (1+1)"` slice. How to do that?

```
str1 = "Some Event 21.08.2019—31.08.2019 Standart (1+1) ,  Some text"
Answer: str2 = "Standart (1+1)"
```

Comment: _I need to get text beetween last data and comma_ What do you mean by "last data"?

Comment: Does all dates you encounter follows `DD.MM.YYYY` format?

Comment: @Daweo Yes, all dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse this with a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = "Some Event 21.08.2019—31.08.2019 Standart (1+1) ,  Some text"
>>> m = re.match(r'.*? \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} (.*?) , .*', str1)
>>> m.group(1)
'Standart (1+1)'
```

The `.*?` matches anything, but only as much as it has to. The `\d{2}` matches two digits. The `\.` matches a period. The `.` matches anything, I use that to match that en-dash without having to enter it. The `(.*?)` matches anything and captures it such that it will then have the `,` later on. In the end I capture just all the remainder with `.*`.

This will break if there is a comma in your desired string. Then it would be better to have `(.*)` for capture and `.*?` at the end.

And by the way, it's likely written “Standard” and not “Standart”.

Comment: I got: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: My first guess would be that you are on a platform which does not have UTF-8 by default or that your file is not encoded as UTF-8. Try replacing that en-dash (`–`) with a plain hypen (`-`) or just replace the single `.` with `.+` to capture multi-byte characters.